# ComboBox DisplayMemberPath IsEditable и выбранный элемент

Tags: wpf, combobox

Имеем XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ComboBox IsEditable="true" Grid.Row="1" Name="f_Combobox" StaysOpenOnEdit="True">
    <ComboBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D7E3BC"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Type="{x:Type System:String}">
        <System:String>ABCDE</System:String>
        <System:String>ABCD</System:String>
        <System:String>ABC</System:String>
        <System:String>AB</System:String>
        <System:String>A</System:String>
      </x:Array>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
  </ComboBox>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=f_Combobox}" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

а вот теперь начинается магия, выбираем элемент `ABC` в `ComboBox` и удалим с конца один символ, заливка белая, т.е. `ComboBox` считает что элемент выбран, а в тексте `ComboBox` говориться что выбран `AB`, хотя в `TextBlock` указывается что выбран элемент `ABCDE`.

Итог получаем:

Выбираем один элемент, меняем текст на другой, а в `SelectItem` `ComboBox` получаем вообще третий элемент, причем пользователь об этом даже не узнает... (`TextBlock` в проекте нет, он создан лишь для демонстрации).

Comment: ...Вопрос в чем?

Comment: Вопрос в том что текст в комбобоксе не совпадает с выбраным элементом.

Comment: как-то сложно для понимания. Cделайте проще, переопределите метод ToString()  у ваших объектов в ComboBox и используйте без DisplayMemberPath

Comment: хм, у меня в `comboBox` выделен `ABCDE` при редактировании. Подозреваю, что при редактировании значения с клавиатуры выбирается не наиболее близкое значение, а первое найденное. Смена порядка на A - AB - ABC - ABCD - ABCDE это подтверждает

Comment: @Gardes сделал, оказывается и с обычными стрингами такая же фишка.

Comment: @Андрей воот, текст один, комбобокс считает, что элемент выбран(заливка белая) а по факту выбран совершенно другой элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стиль `ComboBox` добавим `Setter`

```
<Setter Property="SelectedItem">
  <Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay">
      <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <local:HelpConverter/>
      </MultiBinding.Converter>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ItemsSource"/>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DisplayMemberPath"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

и опишем сам конвертер, который будет в том числе работать и с `DisplayMemberPath` у `ComboBox`

```
public class HelpConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values.Length >= 2 && values[0] is IEnumerable && values[1] is string)
    {
      string displayString = null;
      if (values.Length >= 3 && values[2] is string)
        displayString = (string)values[2];
      IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)values[0];
      IEnumerator enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
      string equalsText = (string)values[1];
      while (enumerator.MoveNext())
      {
        string elementDisplayString = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayString))
          elementDisplayString = enumerator.Current?.ToString();
        else
        {
          if (enumerator.Current != null)
          {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = enumerator.Current.GetType().GetProperty(displayString);
            if (p != null && p.CanRead)
              elementDisplayString = p.GetValue(enumerator.Current)?.ToString();
          }
        }
        if (equalsText.Equals(elementDisplayString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
          return enumerator.Current;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Если кто-нибудь нашел более изящное решение, то прошу ответить, спасибо.

Comment: Ого, ничего себе. Я странное поведение воспроизвёл, но не знал, как к нему подступиться.

Comment: @VladD Причем если переопределять стили, то придется столкнуться с проблемой мерджинга стилей, однако на стеке есть статья по этому...